# unable to bind angular-nested-combobox treeview using angular-nested-combobox library in mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, combobox, treeview

I try to bind combobox treeview using this library from github [angular-nested-combobox](https://github.com/matjas/angular-nested-combobox)

> I'm facing issues when I try to use this library in mvc project. problem is unable to find path for select-group.html which is used inside ng-nested-combobox.js. basically ng-nested-combobox.js is not executed i tried alert('hi') inside ng-nested-combobox.js which is unable to execute :(

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/nestedCombobox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/ng-nested-combobox.js"></script>

  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="demoController as demo">
            <h2>Demo ng-nested-combobox</h2>
            <div class="col">
                <nested-combo-box control-class="col-md-7" control-disabled="false" change-event="demo.changeItem" collection="demo.collection" current-member="demo.activeItem" />
            </div>
            <div class="col code">
                <p>Selected item:</p>
                <pre>{{demo.selectedItem | json}}</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
```

index.js

```
 var app = angular.module('mydemo', ['ui.nested.combobox','angularTreeview', 'ngTable']);
    app.controller('demoController', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $http) {
        var that = this;
        this.collection1 = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'item1',
                    childrens: [
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: 'item1_1'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            name: 'item2_2'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: 'item2',
                    childrens: [
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            name: 'item2_1'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 6,
                            name: 'item2_2',
                            childrens: [
                                {
                                    id: 7,
                                    name: 'item2_2_1'
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 8,
                                    name: 'item2_2_2'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]

                }
        ];



        this.collection = this.collection1;


        this.changeItem = function (value) {
            that.selectedItem = value;
        }

        this.activeItem = {
            id: 2,
            name: 'item1_1'
        }


Index.cshtml

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/nestedCombobox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/ng-nested-combobox.js"></script>

      <div class="container" data-ng-controller="demoController as demo">
                <h2>Demo ng-nested-combobox</h2>
                <div class="col">
                    <nested-combo-box control-class="col-md-7" control-disabled="false" change-event="demo.changeItem" collection="demo.collection" current-member="demo.activeItem" />
                </div>
                <div class="col code">
                    <p>Selected item:</p>
                    <pre>{{demo.selectedItem | json}}</pre>
                </div>
            </div>

index.js


    var app = angular.module('mydemo', ['ui.nested.combobox','angularTreeview', 'ngTable']);
        app.controller('demoController', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $http) {
            var that = this;
            this.collection1 = [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'item1',
                        childrens: [
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                name: 'item1_1'
                            },
                            {
                                id: 3,
                                name: 'item2_2'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'item2',
                        childrens: [
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                name: 'item2_1'
                            },
                            {
                                id: 6,
                                name: 'item2_2',
                                childrens: [
                                    {
                                        id: 7,
                                        name: 'item2_2_1'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        id: 8,
                                        name: 'item2_2_2'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]

                    }
            ];



            this.collection = this.collection1;


            this.changeItem = function (value) {
                that.selectedItem = value;
            }

            this.activeItem = {
                id: 2,
                name: 'item1_1'
            }
```